# Issue when creating numpy array of dtype=numpy.int128

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create an empty array where I am expecting the values to be `random.randint(0, 2 ** 128)`. The values will be written in numpy array. When trying to create empty array using `numpy.int128` as:

```
X = numpy.empty(5, dtype=numpy.int128)
print X
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 62, in <module>
    X = np.empty(5, dtype=np.int128)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'int128'
```

Does it mean numpy does not support this limit of values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the following data types are supported by Numpy

```
Data type   Description
bool_   Boolean (True or False) stored as a byte
int_    Default integer type (same as C long; normally either int64 or int32)
intc    Identical to C int (normally int32 or int64)
intp    Integer used for indexing (same as C ssize_t; normally either int32 or int64)
int8    Byte (-128 to 127)
int16   Integer (-32768 to 32767)
int32   Integer (-2147483648 to 2147483647)
int64   Integer (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)
uint8   Unsigned integer (0 to 255)
uint16  Unsigned integer (0 to 65535)
uint32  Unsigned integer (0 to 4294967295)
uint64  Unsigned integer (0 to 18446744073709551615)
float_  Shorthand for float64.
float16 Half precision float: sign bit, 5 bits exponent, 10 bits mantissa
float32 Single precision float: sign bit, 8 bits exponent, 23 bits mantissa
float64 Double precision float: sign bit, 11 bits exponent, 52 bits mantissa
complex_    Shorthand for complex128.
complex64   Complex number, represented by two 32-bit floats (real and imaginary components)
complex128  Complex number, represented by two 64-bit floats (real and imaginary components)
```

On the top of these:

> Additionally to intc the platform dependent C integer types short,
>   long, longlong and their unsigned versions are defined.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html